# run/debug go application with more then one file on the main package with gogland

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

I downloaded latest Gogland in order to run/debug Go 1.8.1 applications.

I have the exact problem in Latest Intellij Ultimate EAP.

my project's `main` package contains several files, when I try to run/debug it as a `Go Application`, it acts as a `Go Single File`.

which means that when I try to run the application while choosing the main go file, it complains about missing variables definitions from other files on that same directory that are in the `main` package as well.

in the `Run Configuration` when I choose `Package` instead of `File`, I can't choose the `main` package.

so how do I run/debug my project properly ?

thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created the following video https://youtu.be/ko-wKntCLjg to better demonstrate how to achieve this.

There are two options that are also shows in the video:

- the click on the link for adding the ldflags parameter: this is needed for Windows applications in order to allow them to be debugged as well as sometimes in CGO apps (or on OSX) for the same purposes. This is an issue with Go, not the IDE or the the debugger
- the second option is the one that says Single instance only. I prefer my run configurations as such since they allow me to run them a single time and press the same shortcut to restart them when needed.

Depending on your operating system or application type, the first one might be needed, while the second one is purely functional for various use-cases (and as I've said, personal preference).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi! :) thank you for your response. I saw that you chose a package instead of a file and you chose i'm guessing a github repository that contains this project. I didn't upload my project to github yet, and I can't choose 'main' as the package name. so what do i do ?

Comment: You don't need to have your package on Github. As long as it's on your computer in the correct GOPATH place, that's enough for Go (and the IDE) to work.

If you look at the video it shows in the output and you can see the project path at the beginning when I'm editing the Run Configuration from file to package.